# How do I create a hyperlink using google sheets connector in Ballerina?

Tags: integration, connector, ballerina

I want to "insert link" for a cell content of a google sheet. How do I do that in Ballerina? I couldnt find any example in the documentation.

I tried searching for such example in Ballerina By Examples. But couldnt find any. However I was able to successfully edit a cell content inside a cell using google.sheets connector.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [Google API docs](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/cells), you need to send the value as a formula like this:

```excel
=HYPERLINK(link, value)
```

So your Ballerina code might look like this:

```all
gSheet->setCell(
    spreadsheetId,
    sheetName,
    a1Notation = cellNumber,
    value = string`=HYPERLINK(link, cellValue)`,
    valueInputOption = "USER_ENTERED"
);
```

Answer (score -1):

To insert a hyperlink into a cell content using the **google.sheets** connector in Ballerina, you can use the **setCell** function and specify the `valueInputOption` parameter as `USER_ENTERED`. This setting treats the value as user input from the UI and will convert it to a hyperlink.

Here's an example code snippet:

```
import ballerinax/googleapis.sheets;

configurable string token = ?;
configurable string spreadsheetId = ?;
configurable string sheetName = ?;

public function main() returns error? {

    // Initialize the Google Sheets client
    sheets:Client sheetsEp = check new (config = {
        auth: {
            token: token
        }
    });

    // Specify the cell (B2 in this case) where you want to insert the hyperlink
    string cell = "B2";

    // Specify the hyperlink URL that you want to insert into the cell
    string hyperlink = "http://example.com/";

    // Set the hyperlink using the setCell function
    check sheetsEp->setCell(
        spreadsheetId,
        sheetName,
        a1Notation = cell,
        value = hyperlink,
        valueInputOption = "USER_ENTERED"
    );
}
```

Ensure you add configs (token, spreadsheetId, and sheetName) with appropriate values specific to your Google Sheets API credentials and spreadsheet.

For more details about the **setCell** function and other options, you can refer to the official Google Sheets API documentation: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update